How combine multiple .reg Files into One?
I would like to add "Combine reg" to the right click menu when selecting many .reg files and then combine them to one reg file with one "Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00" entry.
There is a tool which can combine .reg files but it has no option to add it to the right click menu. https://media.askvg.com/files/RegFileMerger.zip -https://media.askvg.com/articles/images/Reg_File_Merger.png
